# reroute query string to directory in php

Tags: php, apache, webserver, query-string

I am using [this code from Github](https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy-app/blob/master/index.php). This is a proxy site and currently, if someone enters a link, it goes to a query_string to complete your request.

I want to make it so that it is not a query string and is a directory. For example, if this if this is the original URL

`domain.com/index.php?q=QUERY`

It should be:

`domain.com/search/QUERY` or something similar.

**It must be in only PHP (not .htaccess)!**